# How do we know the list of sharing rules in the org. using SOQL or apex?

Tags: apex, soql, formula

Using SOQL or apex, I would like to read Sharing rules defined in Sharing Settings like for Contact/Accounts in the Org.?

Comment: What is your overall objective? This may be an x-y problem that can be solved in a different way.

Comment: I think you can get help from this response
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/216801/17456